# Can An iBeacon's Scan Response Be Obtained

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ibeacon

I am working with the Core Bluetooth API in iOS 8.4. My code is interacting with a BLE device that is programmed to be an iBeacon. Here is a logging statement produced by my implementation of the CBCentralManager protocol's didDiscoverPeripheral callback function:

2015-09-04 16:23:08.231 CentralManager - Did discover peripheral [CBPeripheral: 0x1742e0b80, identifier = 8B63C7F8-44D5-F3E2-AD40-2916A2513BA9, name = DfuTarg, state = disconnected] with data [[kCBAdvDataIsConnectable: 0]]

The logging statement prints the value of the function's peripheral and advertisementData arguments. Note that the name of the peripheral is printed (BTW: I happen to know that DfuTarg is the correct name of the device being scanned).

From where does iOS acquire this name? It is not part of the Advertising Packet. It must come from a secondary Scan Request / Scan Response exchange, yes? Is it possible for my code to access the Scan Response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `CBPeripheral` name comes from the scan response.  CoreBluetooth automatically requests the scan response data (at least when the app is in the foreground) when an advertisement is detected.

The `didDiscoverPeripheral` method is called with information from both the initial advertisement and the scan response when both have been received by the device.  Essentially, you are already accessing the scan response info by using that callback method.

What's important to note is that you do not have access to raw manufacturer data in this callback when the advertisement is recognized as an iBeacon.  iOS strips it out so you can't access it.  This is true for the manufacturer data bytes present in the advertisement and in the scan response.

See [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html) for more info.